# Is there an option to make ImageLoader.display(...) call block current (UI) thread until image is loaded?

Tags: android, multithreading, universal-image-loader

Yes, I know that I am doing bad things, but...
In some cases I'm using the nostra13's ImageLoader to load images from `res/drawable` folders. Is there a built-in option to block UI thread while image is loading?

I suspect that there may not be such thing, because the primary goal of ImageLoader is to load images from the Internet, and in this case asynchronous mode is the only option. But in my situation this would be handy.
Currently I'm using it for loading and downscaling big background images and it takes some noticeable time.

Comment: Never block the UI thread. Why would you want to do that? I'm using UniversalImageLoader to load, scale and cache Images from the SDCard and its working really smooth. Explain you issue a little bit more.

Comment: @Herrmann The issue is that the fragment shows without background for a fraction of second, and this looks bad. BTW, I can think of other way: hide all other views as well while there's no background.

Comment: Use the UniversalImageLoader to load the image. Also use its in-memory cache. After caching the bg-image show the Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's now a method which can load and scale Bitmap synchronously: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/ImageLoader.java#L550

But it's almost never a good idea to do this, because GUI applications should be responsive, that means — never block UI thread for a noticeable time.

Answer (score 1):

if you're just loading a background for a fragment from the `res/drawable` just do it the "normal" way then.

Put that image in the Fragment XML file as the background of the root view.

of, if it's user/theme selectable, just call `setBackgroundResource` on the root view during `onCreateView`

**edit:**

ImageLoader itself I don't know, but I've been using lately the Picasso library and it's beautiful, handles images VERY VERY well, it's very flexible and it can achieve what u want by calling: `Picasso.with(context).load(<resID>).get()`

Comment: Maybe this is better in some cases, but it seems like there's no caching and it causes hiccups every time fragment view is recreated. (I've did it like that before)

Comment: Actually I use an ImageView that is placed under all other views, because I can do `centerCrop` scaling type to save aspect ratio.

Comment: but let's analyse the problem in hand. The Android Framework is getting a PNG file from the `res/drawable` scaling it and placing in the ImageView, that is causing hipcups in the UI-thread. So you want an ImageLoader library to: get a PNG file from the `res/drawable` scale it and place in the ImageView, but somehow this time, there will be no hipcups? Makes no sense, uh? ps. I edited my answer with a possible approach to what u want, even thou I don't agree with it.

Comment: ImageLoader doesn't cause hiccups every time, because it uses caching, so it doesn't need to decode and resize image every time. (and the cache can be also cleared, for example, in `onTrimMemory`